# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password? But I am using the right username and password

Tags: c#, xml, iis, webrequest, remote-access

I want to connect xml file in remote server. I wrote my code like this:

```
 string XMLPATH = @"\\10.222.54.141\c$\Data\CL\Casinolink30\BuildFiles\Logging\980\NoLog4NetFile.UnitTest.Tests.nunit-results.xml";
        FileWebRequest request = (FileWebRequest)FileWebRequest.Create(XMLPATH);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "Igtcorp123");
        FileWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FileWebResponse;
        Stream stReader = response.GetResponseStream();
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stReader);
        int count = 100;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "test-case")
                {

                    //Console.WriteLine("testcase name:" + reader.GetAttribute("name"));
                    Console.WriteLine("testcase info");
                    Console.WriteLine("name: " + reader.GetAttribute("name").ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine("success: " + reader.GetAttribute("success").ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
```

I got a error: **"logon failure: unknown user name or bad"**.
and I try to do this:

1. input the address (10.222.54.141\c$\Data\CL\Casinolink30\BuildFiles\Logging\980\NoLog4NetFile.UnitTest.Tests.nunit-results.xml) to the address bar,and open. A dialog show up let me add user name and password. I typed  in right word, and I successfully accessed the file.
2. I run the code above. I successfully got the data.
3. I try this program in another computer. They can access the address, but the program does not work.

I am confused about this? Why does this happen?

Now I deployed my project to the server, I can successfully get my data in localhost address(http://localhost:61547/) on server. But I can not get data in my computer remotely through addr: http://10.222.54.140:8080/. What happen? Can any one help me? Much appreciate.

Comment: Here's a guess: when you log in manually from Explorer, the username (administrator) is automatically prepended with the domain name (MYDOMAIN\administrator). Try specifying the domain name explicitly as the third parameter in the `NetworkCredential` constructor.

Comment: Following on from @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) is a link to the documentation.

Comment: There is a message show that:Access to the path '\\10.222.53.125\c$\Data\CL\Casinolink30\BuildFiles\Logging\980\Pgic.CasinoLink.I‌​nterfaces.Gsa.S2S.RegisterClientPlugIn.Test.nunit-results.xml' is denied. But I have inputed my username and password.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the app.config file a bit:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

This might solve the problem.

You can add this as below in the Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy  usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>  
  </system.net>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: My project is ASP.NET website, and I try to find <system.net> in web.config, but I could not find that. So What can I do now?

Comment: @JackZhang ... you can find it in the Web.config file ... i have edited above....

Comment: Now I deployed my project to the server, I can successfully get my data in localhost address(http://localhost:61547/) on server. But I can not get data in my computer remotely through addr: http://10.222.54.140:8080/. What happen? Can any one help me? Much appreciate

Comment: @JackZhang Create a deployment package and use that dll as a service reference in client app and run it on remote machine. When you publish, click on publish at remote site and then specify the remote site address. Take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407.aspx and http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/The-different-ways-to-host-a-WCF-Service-Application-in-a-Web-App.aspx

Comment: I know how to deploy. But my problem is I can get data from remote site in my local computer.There is a message show that:Access to the path '\\10.222.53.125\c$\Data\CL\Casinolink30\BuildFiles\Logging\980\Pgic.CasinoLink.Interfaces.Gsa.S2S.RegisterClientPlugIn.Test.nunit-results.xml' is denied. 
But I have inputed my username and password.

Comment: May be you should set read/write permissions for that xml file externally.Try it.