# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. FTP with C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to access an FTP server that is outside our network to get a CSV file. Here is the code that I am using

```
string XMLPATH = @"\\server\file.csv";
FileWebRequest request = (FileWebRequest)FileWebRequest.Create(XMLPATH);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "password");
FileWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FileWebResponse;
Stream stReader = response.GetResponseStream();
```

When I run this through my console app, I get this message.

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

If I go to the server location to get the file in Windows Explorer, I am able to login just fine and retrieve the file. After that, my application can access the file just fine. I read this previous stack thread

[Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password? But I am using the right username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242990/logon-failure-unknown-user-name-or-bad-password-but-i-am-using-the-right-usern)

And I added this to my config

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

And that changes nothing. I have also tried to add my domain to the Credentials Constructor, but that does not fix anything either. This connection needs to be done as a client application, so the previous post is a little different than mine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

Because I was curious, I ran a Wireshark trace on the call for both the Windows Explorer and my application's request. When using explorer, it send the request using the proper credentials. However when I use the application, it sends the request as the logged in name of my machine (aka my user id). Why is it when I send the request credentials in the request, it still defaults to the logged in user? Is there a setting I have to configure for this?

Comment: Is the server using windows authentication? if so you need the domain\username format

Comment: Any special characters in your password?

Comment: @JMK yes my password has '@' and '!' in it

Comment: Did @Joe's suggestion work? If not, try and put an @ infront of your password. Also does your username have any (such as a backslash)?

Comment: @JMK. Joes suggestion did not work. My username has no backslash or other special characters other than '!' and '@'. Putting an @ infront of the password nets the same result.

Comment: @JMK, I also changed the PW to be simple, no special characters, same issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to specify a domain (or computername):

```
new NetworkCredential("admin", "password", domainOrComputerName)
```

Comment: Adding the domain or computer name nets the same result

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by creating a local user on the server that will run the application. This user would be setup the exact same way as user that has read rights to the FTP server